# How to convert base64 string of image / file to FilePart

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

On my frontend application, images and files are converted to base64 string before being sent to the backend.

I am trying to upload those image and files to gofile.io using a custom webClient with FilePart as a @RequestPart

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST,
          consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  Mono<UploadResumeResponse> uploadResume(@RequestPart("file") FilePart file);
```

I want to convert my base 64 string provided by frontend to a FilePart and then use the client to upload the file. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you have it as base64 then upload it as normal post with body then on backend create DTO class then decode it to bytes and upload it.

```
@Data
    public class UploadDto{
        String file;
    }
    Mono<String> uploadResume(@RequestBody UploadDto request){
        byte[] imgBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(request.getFile());
        
    }
```